# Spying cellphones

Tags: spyware

Today I read an article on a French newspaper that our government listens to us when we use our cell phones. I wonder what type of programming methodoly or technology that allows this espionnage ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that [some kind of spyware](http://ccc.de/en/updates/2011/staatstrojaner) is used in cases like these.

But generally, activity like this is [considered legal](http://echr-online.com/art-8-echr/phone-interceptions-in-light-of-article-8-echr) (or at least somewhat legal/not totally illegal). The keyword here is [lawful interception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawful_interception), and the attack point - so to speak - is generally the [service provider (click for a nice diagram)](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/7600/ios/12-2SR/configuration/lawful_intercept/lawful-int--Book-Wrapper/76LIch1.html#wp1038382). So spyware is not actually needed.

It is hard to find information for this specific case. Here is an article saying the [nsa spied on french phone calls](http://edition.cnn.com/2013/10/21/world/europe/france-nsa-spying/) describing the process like this:

> According to Le Monde, this is how the system worked: "When a
>   telephone number is used in France, it activates a signal which
>   automatically triggers the recording of the call. Apparently this
>   surveillance system also picks up SMS (text) messages and their
>   content using key words. Finally, the NSA apparently stores the
>   history of the connections of each target -- or the meta-data."

This does not sound like spyware, it sounds as if the data was intercepted from the service providers. This also makes more sense: Spyware is better at attacking individuals, intercepting is better for mass surveillance.

It now seems that [France actually collected this data](http://www.theverge.com/2013/10/29/5042860/france-spain-collected-phone-data-not-nsa-say-officials), so maybe this is the case you mean?